# Converting C++ to C#: Passing pointers to functions

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

I have some C++ code that I am trying to convert to C# but I don't fully understand what is happening.

Here is the C++ code:

```
BYTE buffer[150];   // byte is of type ‘unsigned char’
int i;
checksum = 0;


for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    checksum += HexToByte(&buffer[2 + i * 2]);//HOW DO I PASS THIS ARGUMENT
checksum = ~checksum;

BYTE HexToNibble(BYTE HexChar){
    if ((HexChar >= 48) && (HexChar <= 57)) return HexChar - 48;
    if ((HexChar >= 65) && (HexChar <= 70)) return HexChar - 55;
    if ((HexChar >= 97) && (HexChar <= 102)) return HexChar - 87;
    return 0;
}

BYTE HexToByte(BYTE* HexPtr){
    return HexToNibble(HexPtr[0]) * 0x10 + HexToNibble(HexPtr[1]); //AND USE THE ARGUMENT LIKE THIS
}
```

My confusion is regarding how the 'HexToByte' function is using the pointer.  It looks as if we are passing a pointer to a specific index of the buffer array, but then proceed to use it as if it were still an array?

When converting this to C# code I am not sure what the parameter for the HexToByte function should be?

Any help/clarity on the situation would be appreciated.

Here is my code implementation (that doesn't work)

```
   // Modified C++ code
        // Arrays are reference types in .NET framework so I don't need to pass a pointer.
    public static byte HexToByte(byte[] buffer)
    {
        return HexToNibble((byte)((buffer[0] * 0x10) + HexToNibble(buffer[1])));
    }

private static byte HexToNibble(byte HexChar)
{
    if ((HexChar >= 48) && (HexChar <= 57))
        return (byte)(HexChar - 48);
    if ((HexChar >= 65) && (HexChar <= 70))
        return (byte)(HexChar - 55);
    if ((HexChar >= 97) && (HexChar <= 102))
        return (byte)(HexChar - 87);
    return 0;
}


checksum = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
     checksum += utils.HexToByte(buffer[2 + i * 2]); // can't pass this argument ???  WHY CAN I DO THIS IN C++??
```

Comment: The HexToByte parameter should just be a byte array in C#.

Comment: Yes, but then how do I pass a specific index within that byte array, as is being done in the C++ code above?  Also, the HexToByte if a generic function that is used in lots of places.

Comment: You should replace the decimal ASCII numbers with their character literal equivalents, such as `'A'` instead of 65.

Comment: Why should I do that?  I assume this is a suggestion as it doesn't actually solve my problem.

Comment: The `HexToByte` might need to be changed to `HexToByte(byte[] buffer, int index)`.

Comment: Yea, I was considering that... but the HexToByte is used in many places throughout the program... and if i can avoid altering it's signature I would prefer that so I don't have to restructure as much code.

Answer (score 0):

@tinstaafl Thanks for the suggestion

In the C++ code the argument is a pointer that points to a spefic element within the byte array (i.e. some start address).  In the function 'HexToByte' it is using that same pointer to get the element it is pointing to plus the next element.

Here is the C# implementation

```
        public static byte HexToByte(byte[] buffer, int index)
        {
            return HexToNibble((byte)((buffer[index] * 0x10) + HexToNibble(buffer[index + 1])));
        }
        private static byte HexToNibble(byte HexChar)
        {
            if ((HexChar >= 48) && (HexChar <= 57))
                return (byte)(HexChar - 48);
            if ((HexChar >= 65) && (HexChar <= 70))
                return (byte)(HexChar - 55);
            if ((HexChar >= 97) && (HexChar <= 102))
                return (byte)(HexChar - 87);
            return 0;
        }

// calculate the checksum
checksum = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    checksum += utils.HexToByte(buffer, buffer[2 + i * 2]);
```